# Different space above and below displayed equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, belowdisplayskip

I'd like to have the same space above and
below an equation. Currently the space above the
equation seems bigger.
I tried to use `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt}` and
`\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}` but it did not help.

My code:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

%%%----- Mathe ----------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage[squaren,textstyle]{SIunits}
\usepackage{icomma}
    
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{trfsigns}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}
Hierbei wurden die trigonometrischen Beziehungen

\begin{align*}
\cos ^{2} \left(\alpha \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \left( 1 + \cos \left( 2 \alpha \right) \right) \quad \text{und} \quad 2 \cos \left(\alpha \right) \cos \left(\beta \right) = \cos \left(\alpha - \beta \right) + \cos \left(\alpha + \beta \right)
\end{align*}

benutzt. \\
Für das Grundwellen-Luftspaltfeld ($\nu = 1  $ und $\mu = 1$) ergeben die Kraftwellen
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Is there a recommended space between text and equation for a thesis ?

**EDIT**: With the given answer the following part still looks strange:

```
Das Fehlersignal wird aus der Differenz aus Störsignal und Ausgangssignal des Filters gebildet:
\begin{equation}
    e_{k} = d_{k} - y_{k} = d_{k} - \sum_{i=0}^{l-1} w_{i} \cdot x_{k-i}
    \label{eq: Fehlersignal}
\end{equation}
Mit
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \boldsymbol{w} &= \left[ w_{0} \; w_{1} \; ... \; w_{l-1}\right]^{\top} \quad \text{und}\\
        \boldsymbol{x}_{k} &= \left[ x_{k} \; x_{k-1} \; ... \; x_{k-l+1}\right]^{\top}
    \end{aligned}
    \label{eq: Vektoren_Filterkoeff_Eingangssig}
\end{equation}
kann das Fehlersignal auch als inneres Vektorprodukt geschrieben werden
```

Comment: Note that it is never a good idea to have a blank line before displayed math (99% of times this is not what you mean) and ``\\`` should _never_ be used in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are some good practices you don't seem to follow:

1. never have a blank line above a math display;
2. don't use `align*` when `equation*` suffices;
3. don't use `\left` and `\right` unless necessary;
4. don't use `\\` to end paragraphs.

A blank line may follow a math display, if the text begins a new paragraph.

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%%%----- Mathe ----------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage[squaren,textstyle]{SIunits}
\usepackage{icomma}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{trfsigns}

\begin{document}

Hierbei wurden die trigonometrischen Beziehungen
\begin{equation*}
\cos ^{2} ( \alpha ) = \frac{1}{2} ( 1 + \cos ( 2 \alpha ) ) 
\quad \text{und} \quad 
2 \cos ( \alpha ) \cos ( \beta ) = \cos ( \alpha - \beta ) + \cos ( \alpha + \beta )
\end{equation*}
benutzt.

Für das Grundwellen-Luftspaltfeld ($\nu = 1  $ und $\mu = 1$) ergeben die Kraftwellen
und so weiter und so weiter und so weiter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to replace `SIunits` with the more recent, more powerful and actively developed `siunitx` package (but the syntax is different).

Another recommendation: passing the `pdftex` options is not good practice either. You lose in document portability.

Comment: the blank line above a math display was only inserted to have a better readability. Is there a way to do this anyway?

Comment: I edited my post @egreg. Following your instructions the second part still looks strange.

Comment: @Domi1908 I see nothing strange. You're using `fleqn`, so a short line preceding the math display won't trigger the “small skips”. Try removing the option and your displays will immediately improve.

Comment: Okay, for some reason it seems that there is more space above the sigma sign than below. But I have to solve that myself.

Comment: @Domi1908 That's essentially an optical illusion, aggravated by the short line before the display together with `fleqn`.